# Access controls of another Webdynpro ABAP component

Tags: model-view-controller, abap, webdynpro

If I am in a Webdynpro ABAP component, how can I get the attribute of another Webdynpro component, passing the content of some input fields?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, when asking a question here, be sure to include a MCVE code in order for others to answer your specific question
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you should do to pass values from one Webdyn Pro to another:

1. Create both Wendyn Pros.
2. Create in the first WD method which will call the second one.
3. Create in the context of the first WD parameter which should bn passed.
4. Call the WD, after generating its url and appending parameter to be passed.

   ```
   * generating app URL
   call method cl_wd_utilities=>construct_wd_url
      exporting
     application_name              = 'ZZ_CALLABLE_APPLICATION'
      importing
     out_absolute_url              = w_url.

   * appending paramter to URL
   call method cl_http_server=>append_field_url
      exporting
     name  = 'EBELN'
     value = w_value
      changing
     url   = w_url.

   * calling 2nd Webdyn Pro in external window
   DATA: lo_window_manager TYPE REF TO if_wd_window_manager.
         lo_api_component  TYPE REF TO if_wd_component.
         lo_window         TYPE REF TO if_wd_window.

   lo_api_component  = wd_comp_controller->wd_get_api( ).
   lo_window_manager = lo_api_component->get_window_manager( ).

   lo_window         = lo_window_manager->create_external_window( url = w_url ).

   lo_window->open( ).
   ```